# How to add a lean-back background that will appear when focused on the app's icon in Amazon Fire TV?

Tags: java, android

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upqat.jpg) is the image of the leanback I want for my app's icon just like music app in the picture. I am trying to add a leanback background to my app so that when hovered on its icon it will have it in the background. Please provide me with a demo code. I tried to implement the https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback on the firetv but couldn't get any leanback while hovering on its icon.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site and I hope we can help you  find an answer here. Usually, some amount of effort needs to have been made on your part before large amounts of code will be given to you. Have you attempted to do this? What have you tried? Are you running into a specific problem? Do you have any code that you've been working with? Do you have specific error names or messages? Please post it if so. These are typically what's required to help with these types of questions.

Comment: You will find that the commenter above is very patient and understanding compared to some. The way it works: you provide us with code you tried, we give advice if we feel like it. Cheers :)

Comment: If you're going to edit the question, please do so after checking out the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to implement the https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback on the firetv but couldn't get any leanback while hovering on its icon. I want the result the same as http://www.aftvnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/new-fire-tv-ui-featured-apps.jpg where on focussing on the music app, the background does changes to what is required by the app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide app icon and backdrop image while submitting the app to Amazon store. You can find it under multimedia and images section. Fire stick fetches app icon and background images when your app is downloaded.